# Python PIL image transparent issue

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make an image transparent.
This is my image[image: Look at the image]

```
from PIL import Image
   img = Image.open('Frame 0001.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save("img2.png", "PNG")
```

My output image is this:
[image: Output image]

Comment: are you trying to remove white background? because you code seems to do that.

Comment: That is one approach I followed, from some stackoverflow link to the similar question. But it didn't help me GIRISH RAMNANI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Googled a bit and found a package called cv2. Had a tough time installing that package, but the thing I was trying to do was possible

```
import cv2
img1=cv2.imread('m1.jpg')
img2=cv2.imread('logo.jpg')

dst=cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,img2,0.3,0)
cv2.imshow('dst',dst)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.